# Basic custom Http Handler is not even executed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn about the custom Http Handlers. Using VS2019 Community, I created the default ASP.NET Web App with MVC option, target for .NET Framework 4.7.2. Then I defined the custom Http Handler as

```
 namespace WebApplication25
 {
   public class CustomHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
     public bool IsReusable
     {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
     }

     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        context.Response.Write("<h1>WelCome</h1>");
     }
   }
 }
```

In the file Web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.curry" name="CustomHandler" type="WebApplication25.CustomHandler"/>
   </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Then during the standard run with localhost I enter

```
 https://localhost:44325/notes.curry
```

but the code for CustomHandler is not even run. In the browser I get

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 The resource cannot be found. 
 Description: HTTP 404.....
```

Comment: may be because the ``type`` in your ``Web.Config`` is not complete,the ``.dll`` is missing.Check the ``route`` too. example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I tried with type="WebApplication25.CustomHandler,WebApplication25" but it does not make any difference. The link assumes older MVC versions because its web.config uses <httpHandlers> and the current version requires <handlers>. Also, you cannot add Route because the controller is not used here